# Facebook 'share' button not functioning properly on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, firefox

My BigCartel site's Facebook 'share' button inside of my products' "QUICK LOOK" modal works perfectly fine on Chrome (although it isn't positioned correctly yet), except on Firefox, it doesn't work unless you click into the "QUICK LOOK" modal once on a product, then exit, and click back into it for the same product. I'd really appreciate some help on this one.

**Here's what the code for the Facebook 'share' button looks like, scripts and all:**

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>

  <li id="social_facebook">
  <div class="social_action">
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com{{ product.url  }}" data-type="button"></div>
  </div>
  </li>
```

**Here's the page I'm working on (hover over a product and click the "QUICK LOOK" button (that opens the modal):**
http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/products

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your problem but fb-root only needs to be included in a page once (preferable just after the opening body tag)

from what I see of your code it is being added for every product on the page.

move it to the top along with the script. it might be that firefox cant deal with loading it multiple time and it might fix it.

Comment: It didn't work. Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to go back to basics with you but when somethings not working thats what to do right...

so just after the opening body tag insert this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=476675579110595";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This only needs to be referenced once so remove all other occurrences of it on the page.

Then where ever you want a share button insert this code

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="your url" data-type="button"></div>
```

replacing the data-href= with the product url.

sorry again for being blunt about this but that is the only reason I can think of why it wouldn't be working correctly.

Let me know when you make the changes and I'll take a ganer at the link again if you would like :)

Comment: Okay, I did all that just now like you said, and it's still not working. Wanna' take a gander at it?

Comment: looks like firefox is rendering the iframe with width and height set to 0.

adding this to your stylesheet should solve the issue

#social_links #social_facebook iframe {
    width: 55px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}

Comment: That worked! :) But now, the positioning is all weird on Firefox compared to Chrome (Chrome was never positioned correctly though) do you know how to fix that too?

Comment: This should fix it in chrome 

#social_facebook * {
vertical-align: top!important;
}

and adding min-width:60px; to .product_images ul#social_links li 

should fix the firefox issue

Comment: Alright so it works :) but in order for it to position correctly, I still need to click inside the modal and exit it, and click back inside of it on the same product.

Comment: adding this to you stylesheet should fix the firefox issue 

.fb_iframe_widget span{min-width:60px!important;}

Comment: No Worries I have to say it's a nice looking site but will have to criticise your use of id's.

id's are supposed to be unique and not really used for styles. you should be using classes for that.

but other than that I like it :)

Comment: Haha thanks! :) I'll remember that next time. Can I ask you something else? Do you know how I could get the 3 little images under the Home page's slider to load faster when on hover? They're basically just background images via CSS that change on hover.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think preloading the second image is your best bet.

Here is a link to cssTricks tutorial 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/